# JSONP throwing script error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am making an AJAX request to a REST API that is not under my control. I was getting cross-origin error because of which I set the dataType to "jsonp". But, now it is throwing a script error saying "Unexpected token :". When I look at the Network tab of Chrome tools, I can see the request being placed and the response getting back. This is how the response looks like:

```
{"uniqID":"1427907503","membersID":"1245678","isTypeAuth":null,"secretKey":"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"}
```

Now, I am thinking this is probably because the REST API itself doesn't send back JSONP. How can I resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suppose that your API returns `Content-Type: text/javascript`, so browser tries to execute the response. You should manually set this header to `application/json`.

Comment: how do you know it was designed to work as a JSONP service? and if so, are you sure you know what does the service expects you to send it?

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev: I can set the return type? I thought we can only set the  contentType that we send in the AJAX request.

-- vsync: I know that it DOESN'T return JSONP which is the problem.